# Printing a PDF from ASP .Net (c#) using Acrobat Reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing

I am trying to print a PDF using ASP (C#) through Adobe Reader -the problem is it does work on my local machine but not on server. On my local it starts Adob eReader in minimized state and I can see the file present inside Printer's "See what's printing" window. But on the server I can see the process has started from Task Manager but there's no UI visible as well no file in printer's list.

I though it may be a permission issue but after trying the following steps - it still does not work.

What I have tried.

1. As by default it runs under DefaultAppPool user - so I created a new App pool under the admin user, it now starts the process under admin but still I can't see the UI and no output on printer.
2. I added permission "Allow service to interact with desktop" to IIS Admin Service following this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555134 - but no difference.

My current code

```
string args = string.Format("/s /o /h /t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", filepath, printerName);

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.AdobeReaderPath,
    Arguments = args,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    ErrorDialog = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "print",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};

var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: You really don't want to do that. Not only is it a violation of the license agreement but Adobe Reader just wasn't engineered to run as a service. They don't test for security flaws in that kind of environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the Application Pool Advanced settings, make sure you set the option
"**Load User Profile**" to **True** on the server.

Comment: Thanks. It was set to FALSE before so I set it to TRUE, but still no difference -  still runs in background with no UI and no printing.